# Slide show images it just working one time on next button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a slide show consistent of tags and each tag is made up of
collection of images, and I have two buttons (next previous),
I want when I click on next button show first a set of images showing
all in a row and when I click on previous button show
the set of previous images after click next button.

1. its working fine for one time in only next button but when click
   prev did not working and not show the set of  previous images.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cjssor=0;
    var ele;
    var ejssor=["jssor_1","jssor_2","jssor_3","jssor_4"];
       var`ljssor=document.getElementById("txt")           
           .getElementsByClassName("jssor").length;`
    function next(n)
    {
    cjssor+=1;                 
    if(cjssor>=ljssor)
    {        
    cjssor=0;
    }
    ele=document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=ejssor[cjssor];  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$(ele);
    });
    }

    function previous(m){
    cjssor-=1;        
    ctc=document.getElementById("kk").innerHTML=ejssor[cjssor];
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$(ctc);
    });
    }
    </script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1");
           });
           </script>
          <body>
<a class="next" id="next" onclick="next(1)">&#10095;</a>
<a class="prev" id="prev" onclick="previous(1)">&#10094;</a>
<!--------------------------------jssor1--------------------------->
<div id="jssor_1"  class="jssor" style="position:absolute;margin:0 
   auto;top:60px;left:160px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;        
   visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
   <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" 
    style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;        
    height:100%;text- align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">

    <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;
      width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;
       left:0px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/01.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/022-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/023-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/03.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/024-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/025-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/05.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/026-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/06.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/027-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!--------------------------------jssor2--------------------------->
     <div id="jssor_2"  class="jssor" style="position:absolute;margin:0 
      auto;top:60px;left:160px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden; 
      visibility: hidden;">
       <!-- Loading Screen -->
       <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" 
       style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;        
       height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
       <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;
        width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;    
        top:0px ; left:0px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
        <img data-u="image" src="img/07.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/022-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/08.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/023-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/09.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/024-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/10.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/025-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/11.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/026-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/12.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/027-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>

<!--------------------------------jssor3--------------------------->

 <div id="jssor_3" class="jssor" style="position:absolute;margin:0 
  auto;top:60px;left:160px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;  
   visibility: hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" 
     style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;     
     text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
     <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;
      width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;
     left:0px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/13.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/022-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/14.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/023-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/15.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/024-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/16.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/025-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/17.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/026-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/18.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/027-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>

<!--------------------------------jssor4--------------------------->

  <div id="jssor_4"  class="jssor" style="position:absolute;margin:0 
   auto;top:60px;left:160px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" 
    style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;
    text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
        <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;
     width:38px;height:38px;" src="img/spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;
    left:0px;width:800px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/19.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/022-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/20.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/023-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/21.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/024-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/22.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/025-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/23.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/026-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="img/24.jpg" />
            <div data-u="thumb">
                <img data-u="thumb" class="i" src="img/027-s96x48.jpg" />
                <span class="ti">Title</span><br />
                <span class="d">Slide Description</span>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Comment: Please update your code snippets.  It appears that they aren't displaying in the way that you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Change inner html dynamically will not work.
We will implement `$ReloadSlides` and `$AppendSlides` api to load new slides dynamically later.

For you case at the moment, I think you can create a new slider and hide previous slider when mouse click.

Note that before you show another slider, you can `$Pause` and hide the element of the previous slider.